# Passing an float value to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 controllers and i would like to send a `float` from `LevelViewController` to `ViewController`. But it always sends it as 0 (zero). Here is my LevelViewController.m

```
ViewController *inGame = [[ViewController alloc] init];
enemySpeedShouldBe = 0.800f - 0.07f * levelSelected;
inGame.enemySpeed = enemySpeedShouldBe;
```

Where `levelSelected` and `enemySpeedShouldBe` are also floats.

`NSLog(@"%f", levelSelected)` gives me the correct value (1.0, 2.0 etc.), but when I send it to `ViewController`, it's equal to 0.

Here is my ViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic) float enemySpeed;
```

I've read about this issue but I couldn't find any way to make it work.

--/--/--/--/--/--/--/--/--/--/--EDIT--/--/--/--/--/--/--/--/--/--

here is my enemy millisecond counter methods in "ViewController.m"

```
-(void)enemyStartCounter{
    enemyMs += 0.001;
    if(enemyMs > enemySpeed){  // i use 'enemySpeed' nowhere except here
        [enemyTimer invalidate];
        [fire setHidden:YES];
        [self enemyFired];
    }
}
-(void)enemyCounter{
    enemyMs = 0;
    enemyTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001/1.0 target:self selector:@selector(enemyStartCounter) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

and my button touchup inside action method in "LevelViewController.m"

```
- (void)didTapLevel:(UIButton *)buttonn{
    levelSelected = (float)buttonn.tag + 1.0f ;
    ViewController *inGame = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    enemySpeedShouldBe = 0.800f - (0.07f * levelSelected);
    inGame.enemySpeed = enemySpeedShouldBe;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1player" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Where are you logging `enemySpeed`?

Comment: i am not logging it anywhere it was just a test to see the value of it

Comment: @user3025584 In your question you stated that you called `NSLog(@"%f", enemySpeed)` in ViewController.m. Where exactly (what method) is this line of code?

Comment: -(void)enemyStartCounter{
        NSLog(@"%f", enemySpeed);  // here
        enemyMs += 0.001;
        if(enemyMs > enemySpeed){
            [enemyTimer invalidate];
            [fire setHidden:YES];
            [self enemyFired];
        }

Comment: Change your references to `enemySpeed` to `self.enemySpeed`.

Comment: @rmaddy it didn't work I'm sorry

Comment: Where are you presenting or pushing `inGame` view controller ?

Comment: Before you try anything else please make sure the type of your `enemySpeedShouldBe` is float or double and not int.

Comment: @JordanMontel in a button action method and other functions in it are working

Comment: When is `enemyStartCounter` called?

Comment: Add the code when you click on the button.

Comment: i added methods that you asked for. please check out and help me. thank you

@Wain its called in another counter method, and that other counter method is called in another method :)

Comment: See my answer, that is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point in your code you are creating this instance of `ViewController`, configuring it with a value for `enemySpeed`, and then probably throwing it away.

Somewhere else, another instance is being created. This instance isn't configured, but you're calling `enemyStartCounter` on it, so it logs a zero.

You need to ensure that you understand what instances of each class you have and how they're being used. Your view controller could be created from a Storyboard segue, in this case you need to get a reference to it by intercepting the segue using `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

---

This code creates 2 different instances:

```
- (void)didTapLevel:(UIButton *)buttonn{
    ViewController *inGame = [[ViewController alloc] init]; // create first instance
    inGame.enemySpeed = enemySpeedShouldBe;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1player" sender:self]; // create second instance
}
```

So what you should be doing is:

```
- (void)didTapLevel:(UIButton *)buttonn{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1player" sender:self]; // create single instance
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ViewController *inGame = (ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController]; // get single instance
    inGame.enemySpeed = enemySpeedShouldBe;
}
```

Comment: thanks for help but i didn't completely understand that segue thing... can you give more specific info please. it will really help

Comment: OMG it worked thaaaaaaank you so much. i was fighting with this issue for 3 days. finally... thank you

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create a NSNumber property to do this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *enemySpeed; // in your viewController


 // passing the parameter
 inGame.enemySpeed = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(0.800f - 0.07f * levelSelected)];
```

Then if you pass the property between the controllers you can do this :

```
 NSLog(@"%f", [enemySpeed floatValue]);
```

Comment: Have you used a NSLog before you add the value to the inGame property?
I mean, `float *enemySpd = 0.800f - 0.07f * levelSelected); NSLog(@"%f",enemySpeed);` and then `inGame.enemySpeed = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:enenmySpd];`What output do you get?